# Android Hidden Xml file

Tags: android, xml

I'm creating a app in Android where I want to specify data in specific formats so I later can do sorting and retrieval from the file.

I've read a bit about parsing XML files, but I don't want my file visible in the storage, rather a part of the application itself "hidden in the app".

Has anyone done this before?

//Henrik

Comment: As Simon says put it into /res/raw and you may crypt/encrypt it if you need..

Comment: `res/xml/` is generally a better choice for XML files, as you can immediately get it parsed via an `XmlPullParser`, and it will parse approximately 10 times faster than from `res/raw/` or a regular file. XML resources, such as those in `res/xml/`, are converted into a "binary XML" format that makes them much faster to parse.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this immediately!